# Can luaL_loadfile() be replaced by luaL_loadbuffer()?

Tags: c, lua

I have have a working project like with the following code , running on Visual Studio 2013, windows 7 N. 
I tried to replace luaL_loadfile() with luaL_loadbuffer(L,s,strlen(s),name), so that I could put the script as a string together in the main instead, because in my other project with IAR, I have problem with opening file in the project, but I managed to call a lua script directly with putting the script as a string in the main(). My question would be: how does this luaL_loadbuffer() work? I mean, if I understand this function correctly, luaL_loadbuffer(L,s,strlen(s),name), the "s" means a string. I tried to debug with luaL_loadbuffer(), but could not passing the debug, always got error status= 2. Besides I also see somebody else used luaL_loadbuffer() to load the script file, so I am confused now. Can anyone help me?

```
-- last.lua
function f ()
print("Hello from Lua")
end

#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double z;
    int error;    

    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    if (luaL_loadfile(L, "last.lua") || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0)) 
    {
        printf("error: %s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        return -1;
    }

    lua_getglobal(L, "f");
    if (!lua_isfunction(L, -1))
    {
        lua_pop(L, 1);
        return -1;
    }

    if (lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0) != 0) 
    {
        printf("error running function `f': %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        return -1;
    }

    lua_close(L);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `luaL_loadbuffer(L,s,strlen(s),name);` should just work fine if `s` does not contain syntax errors. What is its return code?

Comment: If you include script text by enclosing each line in double quotes, then you'll have syntax errors all over the script, because newlines lost.

Comment: Thank, I managed to pass the compiling and get the expected result by running the same project in another laptop. I don't know what happened, and the string just looks like this: char *script = "function f()\n print(\"Hello from lua\")\n end";  BTW, @Vlad, I also tried your way, it works fine as well.

Comment: But what do you mean "What is its return code?" @Ctx

Comment: @Beni `int st = luaL_loadbuffer(L,s,strlen(s),name);` <- in `st` the return code of luaL_loadbuffer is stored.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to do this, assuming you load the file as one chunk (and not try to process it by line or by some other chunk as this will probably make those parts invalid Lua code). There is an [example](http://www.lua.org/pil/24.1.html) in "Programming Lua" that shows how `loadbuffer` can be used.

Two additional suggestions: (1) don't remove new lines from the file you read and pass it exactly as is to `loadbuffer` (otherwise `--comment\ncode` will turn `code` into comment), (2) make `name` look like `@name` as it will make `name` to be recognized as the file name (for example, in errors thrown from that code). See description under "source" in [4.9](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#4.9).

Comment: Oh, thanks, I managed to pass the compiling and get the expected result by running the same project in another laptop, I don't know what happened. BTW, these two functions are different, the luaL_loadbuffer() can be used to load script as a string.